# Upload picture from iPhone in Web App

Tags: php, iphone, web-applications

I have built a web-app for iphone using iUi framework. As you may already know, mobile safari doesn't support file upload form element. My application allows school administrators to do classroom walk-throughs, marking off what they see in the classroom (in web form survey). I would like to add the ability for them to upload a picture taken with their iPhone or Touch into the mysql database using php or other technologies.

How can I do this without going 'Native'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

does Safari completely remove the "file" input form from forms???
I guess it makes sense, since you cannot open a file browser in your iphone...

Have you tried with the php PEAR Upload package? maybe you could trick it by using a text input form, but then your users would probably have to enter the full file path manually, which might be complicated and confusing...

From what I see [here](http://www.how-to.com/article/details/209), it looks like you can only do it via connecting your iphone to a pc....